# Pandas: `array_split` on a column of arrays, why don't I find back the max of the column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My initial column looks like this:

```
                       spread%  
0  0.002631183029370956687450895171  
1  0.002624478865422741694443794361  
2  0.002503969912244045131633932303  
3  0.002634517528902797001731827513
```

(I have 95000 rows in total)
What I wanted to do is to divide these spreads into 100 bins. That's what I did:

```
spread_range = np.linspace(0.000001, 0.0001, num=300)
dfspread = pd.DataFrame(spread_range,columns=['spread%'])

sorted_array = np.sort(df['spread%'])
dfspread['spread%']=np.array_split(sorted_array, 300)
dfspread['spread%'] = dfspread['spread%'].str[1]
```

I had to first create a dataframe with random values (spread_range) then replace these values by the good values(last line). I did not know how to do it in one step... 
This is my output:

```
                                     spread% 
295     0.006396490507889923995723419182
296     0.006601856970328614032555077092
297     0.006874901899230889970177366191
298     0.007286400912994813194530809917
299     0.008012436834225554885192314445
```

but I do not find my maximum value which is: `0.02828190624663463264290952354`
Any idea why?

Comment: I don't really understand the question (your title says `pd.qcut` but I can't see it in your code?) but you could try this: `pd.cut(your_initial_series, 100)`.

Comment: Yup my bad sorry!

Comment: The line `dfspread['spread%'] = dfspread['spread%'].str[1]` throws an `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values` (pandas 0.23.4). What is it designed to do?

Comment: As the line before divide the spreads into arrays, the goal of the last line is to take one element of the array. [0.00002839,0.00002935], str[1]= 0.00002935

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems you want two different things. Do you want to split into bins that are equally spaced or equally sized? What do you mean by "I cannot find the maximum"?